# adjust time and date according to timestamp in excel

Tags: excel

I have a time stamp in a data set like this : 2021-04-21 22:25:20 -0800 , this is all in one cell.

This is formatted as Date, time, Timezone Offset.

I am in the GMT time zone, so the actual time and date the above timestamp adjusted for the timezone is 2021-04-**22** **06**:25:20 (note the time and date have changed as they have been brought forward by the timezone offset)

Is there a way in excel i can apply a formula to "normalise" these time stamps so that they are adjusted for my timezone ?

Ive tried myself but im not sure of the best way to do this, ive tried spliting the data into 3 separate columns, (eg. date, time, timezone) and then adjusting the time by the timezone offset, but this wont adjust the date.

Comment: You merely subtract the offset.  Separate **only** the offset into a separate column.  Leave the date and time together as a date/time. Or, if you separate all three, add all three:  `=Date + Time - offset`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of an automated setting to convert time zones, but you can do it splitting in two, date/time and offset. Let's say date/time in A1 and offset in B1. If you want converted time in C1 then it would be:

```
=A1-(B1/100/24)


If A1=2021-04-21 22:25:20
   B1=-0800
```

then C1 would be

```
2021-04-21 14:25:20
```

note: B1, the offset, is divided by 100 to obtain the hour part and then into 24 as excel counts time in fractions of a day